# I receive a configure build path using poi-scratchpad-3.2-FINAL.jar

Tags: java, classpath, apache-poi

I'm using `poi-scratchpad-3.2-FINAL.jar` to read a `DOC` file in Java but I have a `configure build` path problem.

I checked the build path but everything seems OK.

The error line :

```
HWPFDocument document=new HWPFDocument(fis);
```

The actual error:

> Unresolved compilation problem:
>
> The type org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.POIFSFileSystem cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required

Comment: Can you post the actual error please

Comment: Why are you using Apache POI 3.2? It's [almost 6 years old!](http://poi.apache.org/changes.html#3.2-FINAL)

Comment: i just don't know what to do,i'm confused

Answer (score 1):

Looks like **poi-scratchpad** depends on **org.apache.poi:poi** (http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails|org.apache.poi|poi-scratchpad|3.2-FINAL|jar):

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
   <version>3.2-FINAL</version>
</dependency>
```

Make sure it's on your classpath.

Comment: in the referenced libraries,i opened the jar file but all the classes are "Source Not Found"

Comment: Source not Found means your IDE don't know how to get *-sources.jar files that contain sources - is not problem in general, but to have the sources is helpful. Most popular IDEs can download them for you from central repositories that you configure. But for that you project needs be configured as a maven project for example.